# Apex Scheduler Salesforce, execution error

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a big problem with apex scheduler.
I've always get this error message, when I try to execute the scheduler:
"Global type must be contained inside of a global class"

This is the code example:
    `global class updateData implements Schedulable {        global void execute (SchedulableContext SC) {        DataContact dContact = new DataContact();        dContact.UpdateContact();        }        }`

Thanks!

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to execute this code inside the Developer Console. The Developer Console does not really support creating global classes (which means you can't implement the Schedulable interface inside it). If you are just trying to anonymously call `UpdateContact`, then you can simply type this into the Developer Console:

```
DataContact dc = new DataContact();
dc.updateContact();
```

If you are trying to create a schedulable object to schedule calls to DataContact then you should create an Apex class with the code that you posted and then schedule it using the 'Schedule Apex' button on the Apex Classes page.

Comment: Actually I used Soql Explorer to execute my apex class. I've created the scheduler apex class (updateData) in salesforce, also the DataContact class. This DataContact class just has one Method updateContact() which only inserting new Contact into my contact list. Thanks for your reply.. any thought maybe?

Comment: @Jay Soql Explorer, like the Developer Console, is 'Anonymous Apex', which doesn't allow global classes. They share all the same restrictions. If you are looking to schedule the UpdateData class, you can either do so through the UI with the 'Schedule Apex' button or, if you have sophisticated timing requirements, by calling `System.schedule` from anonymous apex as detailed here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm.

Comment: I ran also the scheduler through the UI by clicking "Schedule Apex" button in the Apex Classes, but did not produce anything. Should there any Setup actually needed to make the scheduler works?

Comment: Setting something up in the scheduler will cause it to run periodically on a scheduled basis. You can confirm that something is scheduled to run by going to Setup -> Monitoring -> Scheduled Jobs. If your item is on the list, it will run at the given periods. If you just want to call the `updateContact()` method, you can do so by typing the code in my answer into the Apex section of Soql Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Triangle Man.. I'm now successfully run my scheduler.